# Install ASP.Net State Service (2.0 or later) without IIS?

Tags: asp.net, session-state-server

For a server farm, I would like to install the ASP.Net State Service on a non-web server to share with all the web servers.  Is it possible to install the ASP.Net State Service standalone without having IIS installed on its server?  If so, how?

Answer (score 7):

According to this blog entry, [Enabling ASP.NET Session State without Installing IIS](http://reidablog.blogspot.com/2005/05/enabling-aspnet-session-state-without.htm), the answer is **yes**.

First, you need to make sure the ASP.NET State Service is installed on the computer. (Of course you'll need to have the .NET Framework installed on this computer.) Go to the Services section in the Administration Tools and locate the ASP.NET State Service item. If it's not there, drop to the command line, navigate to `%WINDIR%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\*version*\` and enter:

```
aspnet_regiis -i
```

Finally, you'll need to allow remote connections to this server. Go to the Registry and set `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\aspnet_state\Parameters\AllowRemoteConnection` to 1.

Happy Programming!

*Please note that I have not tried these steps myself; rather, I am summarizing the discussion from the Enabling ASP.NET Session State without Installing IIS blog entry I cited at the start of this answer...*

Comment: On Windows 2012 I'm told to install II8 + ASP.Net using Add/Remove features, so install the ASP.Net for your desired version of .Net *only* through Add/Remove Fatures, and then make the registry modification.